# form personalization to restrict alphanumeric in a field in oracle apps 11i

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle-apps

I am new to oracle apps and need some help in restricting alphanumerics to be entered in a field.If any entered a warning message should be displayed like "no alphanumeric characters are allowed in this field."

Oracle apps 11i.

Thanks and Regards,
Sainadh Vennapusa

Answer (score 0):

If you need only numbers ()
In Form Personalization, 
Trigger Event: WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORDS,
Condition:

```
(select nvl( (select 1 from dual 
where regexp_like(column, '^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$')) , '0') as t  from dual)  = '1'
```

In Actions, Type: 'Message' , Message Type: Error, Message Text: 'Provide the error message'